# Is possible do a later function binding knowing its function type and ,later the object type to bind to?

Tags: c++, function, bind, wrapper

I developing kind of generic object creator from classes. The main idea is store the function type in a kind of wrapper and then create the function object with the function type stored and the pointer object or any of object that derives from its base.

This is the generic function object creator class,

```
class CGenericObjectCreator{

    class CFunctionInterface{
    public:
        virtual intptr_t createFunctionObject(intptr_t  ptr)=0;
        ~CFunctionInterface();
    };

    template<class _T, typename _F>
    class CFunctionImplementation:public CFunctionInterface{
        _F function;
    public:

        CFunctionImplementation(const _F & f):function(f){
        }

        virtual intptr_t createFunctionObject(intptr_t obj){

            return (intptr_t)(new std::function<void (intptr_t)>(std::bind((void (_T:: *)(intptr_t))function, (_T *)obj,std::placeholders::_1)));
        }
    };
    CFunctionInterface *function;
public:

    template<typename _R, class _T, typename..._A>
    void setFunction(_R (_T:: *function_type)(_A...)){
        function = new CFunctionImplementation<_T,decltype(function_type)>(function_type);
    }

    intptr_t createFunctionObject(intptr_t obj){
        return function->createFunctionObject(obj);
    }
};
```

In the class CGenericObjectCreator we can see two main function members:

- setFunction: stores the function type.
- createFunctionObject: it does binding and creates function object passing object pointer based of the function type.

As we can see, the object function creator CGenericObjectCreator it has the constraint of bind any function object but only with one parameter as a constraint. Note the casting I'm doing in the function CFunctionImplementation::createFunctionObject,

```
(void (_T:: *)(intptr_t))function
```

Let's see CGenericObjectCreator in action!

First we declaring the following classes,

```
class CObject{

public:
    string m_id;

    void setID(const char * id){
        printf("assign id %s\n",id);
        m_id=string(id);
    }

     ~CObject(){}
};


class CDerivedObject:public CObject{
public:
    ~CDerivedObject(){};
};

class CVirtualDerivedObject:public CObject{
public:

    virtual ~CVirtualDerivedObject(){};
};
```

For instance, we can save the function CObject::setID type with the following secuences,

```
CGenericObjectCreator generic;
generic.setFunction(CObject::setID);
```

Note that with this CObject::setID the function type is (CObject:: *)(const char *) and we retrieve its object type class too that is take as _T in parameter template.

Now if I create object type CObject type,

```
CObject *object = new CObject();
```

I can create a generic function object doing that,

```
intptr_t cobject_set_id_fun = functor.createFunctionObject((intptr_t)object);
```

And call the function object (aka, object->setID("")) through a function pointer std::function casting,

```
(*((std::function<void (intptr_t)> *)(cobject_set_id_fun)))((intptr_t)("cobject_set_id_fun called"));
```

and... Believed or not it works!

Also its works for CDerivedObject because it derives from CObject class,

```
CDerivedObject * derived_object=new CDerivedObject();
intptr_t cderived_object_set_id_fun = functor.createFunctionObject((intptr_t)derived_object);
(*((std::function<void (intptr_t)> *)(cobject_set_id_fun)))((intptr_t)("cderived_object_set_id_fun called"));
```

Unfortunately, I have not the same luck for CVirtualDerivedObject,

```
CVirtualDerivedObject* virtual_derived_object=new CVirtualDerivedObject();
intptr_t cvirtual_derived_object_set_id_fun = functor.createFunctionObject((intptr_t)virtual_derived_object);
(*((std::function<void (intptr_t)> *)(cvirtual_derived_object_set_id_fun)))((intptr_t)("cvirtual_derived_object_set_id_fun called?")); // <-- sometimes crashes!
```

It crashes on some compilers. I know this is due of virtual functions, because memory map it changes on virtual classes at run-time. At function CFunctionImplementation::createFunctionObject, the compiler needs to know the real object type (CVirtualDerivedObject in this example) we are passing on and, as we can see, we are passing always CObject type as we can see in this example.

I tested that, If the compiler know the type of the class (i.e CVirtualDerivedObject) for creating object function, it doesn't crashes. I mean doing that,

```
virtual intptr_t createFunctionObject(intptr_t obj){

                return (intptr_t)(new std::function<void (intptr_t)>(std::bind((void (_T:: *)(intptr_t))function, (CVirtualDerivedObject *)obj,std::placeholders::_1)));
}
```

The main idea it would be pass the type of object at time when I bind the function object, like this,

```
template<typename _D>
virtual intptr_t createFunctionObject(intptr_t obj){

                return (intptr_t)(new std::function<void (intptr_t)>(std::bind((void (_T:: *)(intptr_t))function, (D *)obj,std::placeholders::_1)));
}
```

But as far as I know virtual functions cannot be templated. But I don't know if there's some remote possibility to pass by through a magic template I would be very thankful to know it!

Comment: The result of converting a pointer to member function to a different pointer-to-member-function type is unspecified, thus the general idea behind your pattern may break. In addition, identifier that begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (for example, `_T`) is always reserved by the compiler.

Comment: @xskxzr it could break but make a constraint having a pointer (for instance setID is const char *) as a parameter I think that can be read into as intptr_t  because it meets the same conditions, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure. [\[expr.reinterpret.cast\]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#10) says the result is unspecified but I don't know whether there are other rules making such cases well-defined.

Comment: @xskxzr Thanks for the info. I know,  is a bit challenge what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Looks like you want factory design pattern

Comment: @seccpur More or less but having a constraint that the function pointer is member of one of their parents and only one parameter as a pointer type. I think what I'm trying is a bit experimental.